# How can I prevent making new Untitled document when Mac OS X document based application start up?

Tags: macos, document-based

I'm making a new Mac OS X application. (not an iPhone app)
This is document-based application.

It shows a new "Untitled" document instance automatically when it starts up. How can I block this behavior? I wish my application show no window at start up.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**[Apple Doc, Document Based application overview - FAQ](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Documents/Tasks/FAQ.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000954):**

> How can I keep my application from
>   creating an untitled document at
>   launch?
>
> Implementing the
>   applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:
>   method to return NO in your
>   application delegate prevents the
>   application from opening an untitled
>   file when launched or activated. If
>   you do want to open an untitled file
>   when launched, but don't want to open
>   an untitled file when already running
>   and activated from the dock, you can
>   instead implement
>   applicationShouldHandleReopen:hasVisibleWindows:
>   to return NO